# WebMatrix: Opening websites from network folders

Tags: asp.net, windows, macos, webmatrix, network-drive

Me and my friends are building up a small scale website but working in our own workplaces. We use WebMatrix for building websites. Our setup is such that we're all on the same intranet, the files are kept on our file server.

We're facing a problem this way. In WebMatrix, there is an option to Open Folder as Website. If I try to navigate to my network folder, where the files are kept, and select the folder, the WebMatrix opens it properly but fails in running the website on IIS. The IIS cannot locate the files, I'm guessing it does not work with network folders.

I also tried mapping network drives and then working on it. Still it doesn't work, the IIS fails to read the website.

How can I make the WebMatrix + IIS 8.0 work with my network topology.  I've read someplace that if I make the My Documents point to a network folder then the WebMatrix will work, instead of creating a mapped network drive. I can't figure it out how to accomplish this. See this link if you can figure it out. http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/troubleshooting-webmatrix/microsoft-webmatrix-my-documents-on-network-shares

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

P.S. Making the WebMatrix work with network website files has another reason. This way I can use VirtualBox with multiple operating systems and browsers to test the websites cross platform capabilities, and if you know the VirtualBox connects to the Host OS via network folders.

Regards
Faraz Azhar

Comment: you can also make the virtual box create a virtual network with the host pc --> host website on localhost and access via VirtualBox to the virtual network ip of your "hostPC"

Answer (score 1):

I spent a fair amount of time trying to get this to work as you described and ultimately gave up.  Instead, especially since you are in a group environment, you should keep on the file server the "master" copy of the website.  On your local drive, you keep your "working" copy where you and only you are making changes.  When you're satisified with your changes, check them back into the master.
To accomplish this, either

- do it manually, or (shudder) by batch files
- install git or another configuration management tool
- use github (which is what we do) or another cloud configuration management tool

It may seem like a lot of effort, but a properly set up config management tool like git is incredibly useful even if there's just one developer, and just about mandatory for 2 or more developers.

Comment: yea its something I couldn't seem to get a decent work-around for. Seems so simple yet complicated. My one option was to use a realtime file sync utility, like dsyncrhonize or something. Another option I had thought of was to use dropbox or google drive, but then all of my terminals are not connected to internet and it seems a waste of internet resources just for file sync ability. Thanks I'll take a look at github, I've never used it before.